# Webpack error when i install react.(when i try to use "npm start" to start a sever)

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

[it's the log of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbusc.png)

when i try to start a sever by use "npm start",it give me this.
 My configuration is below .

```
    var config = {
  entry: './main.js',

  output: {
    path: '/C:\Users\34337\reactApp',
    filename: 'index.js',
  },

  devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 7777
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',

      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    }]
  }
};
module.exports = config;
```

after i replace "loders" to "rules",it shows that i didn't set 'mode' option.
[the error after that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wiW6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check of `babel-cli` and `babel-loader` installed in your env, 
if not installed, run command: `npm install --save babel-cli babel-loader babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-react` then rerun your starting script.

And configuration `module` point should looks like this:

```
module: {
 rules: [
   {
     test: /\.js$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     use: 'babel-loader',
     query: {
       presets: ['es2015', 'react']
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

For now you can ignore `mode` warning.
Pay attention of my `module` config, and set `babel-loader` instead of `babel`.